# SQL query sumup quantity of each item from inventory and sales and subtract them

Tags: sql

I need help on the following program that am working on. 
I have two tables the inventory_list table and the Sales_Report Table, am trying to calculate the items left in the inventory_list once sales are made in the Sales_Report Table.

The tables are as follows:

InventoryList Table

```
ProductName       Quantity   
Dell Laptops          12
Wrist Watches         6
Lenovo Laptops        5
Dell Laptops          4
Wrist Watches         3
HP Laptops            15
```

SalesReport Table

```
ProductName       Quantity   
Dell Laptops          1
Wrist Watches         2
Lenovo Laptops        1
Dell Laptops          1
Wrist Watches         1
```

I wrote the following query but its giving me wrong figures,
 the idea is for  the query to add products with the same name and subtract when sales are made.

```
select  i.ProductName, 
        (sum(i.Quantity - r.Quantity)) AS  number_items_left 
from InventoryList i  
    JOIN Report_details r  ON i.ProductName = r.ProductName
GROUP BY i.ProductName, r.ProductName
```

The expected results should be.
ProductName    number_items_left 
Dell Laptops          14
Lenovo Laptops        4
Wrist Watches         6

Comment: You can remove r.ProductName from the GROUP BY, not needed, makes no difference.

Comment: Do subtraction after doing sum.

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result? (Formatted text, please.)

Comment: Post the expected result..

Comment: @Pரதீப் Expected result is items left in inventory.

Comment: Edit your question add the expected result - as formatted text!!!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of your query, try this:

```
select  i.ProductName, 
        i.sum - COALESCE(r.sum,0) AS  number_items_left 
from (SELECT 
         i.ProductName, 
         sum(i.Quantity) as sum 
      FROM InventoryList i
      GROUP BY i.ProductName) i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
         r.ProductName, 
         sum(r.Quantity) as sum 
      FROM  Report_details r 
      GROUP BY r.ProductName) r
ON i.ProductName = r.ProductName
```

Explenation: In your query, you are joining on `ProductName` column **DUPLICATING** data. That is the problem.

Comment: @Pரதீப் The simpliest mistakes are the worst.

Comment: Rokuto, if i want to show even items that i havent sold and i want show numbers not the NULL word how do i do that.

Comment: @LBjoshua I've just edited my answer. You need to change `JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` (because there can be items, which are not selled) and change `r.sum` to `COALESCE(r.sum,0)` (or equivalent, I don't know which DBMS you are using).

Answer (score 0):

You need to sum individual tables first. It is becaues you have duplicate data and joining tables before summing up will create cross join. Here is updated version.

```
create table InventoryList  (ProductName nvarchar(50), Quantity int)
create table SalesReport (ProductName nvarchar(50), Quantity int)

insert into InventoryList values
('Dell Laptops',12),
('Wrist Watches',6),
('Lenovo Laptops',5),
('Dell Laptops',4),
('Wrist Watches',3),
('HP Laptops',15)

insert into SalesReport values
('Dell Laptops',1),
('Wrist Watches',2),
('Lenovo Laptops',1),
('Dell Laptops',1),
('Wrist Watches',1)


select i.ProductName, i.sumQuantity, s.sumQuantity, i.sumQuantity - COALESCE(s.sumQuantity,0) as inventory
FROM
(
select  ProductName,sum(Quantity) as sumQuantity
from InventoryList
GROUP BY ProductName
) i
LEFT JOIN
(
select  ProductName,sum(Quantity) as sumQuantity
from SalesReport
GROUP BY ProductName
) s
on 
i.ProductName = s.ProductName
```

The result of this query is

```
ProductName    sumQuantity  sumQuantity inventory
Dell Laptops    16           2            14
HP Laptops      15           NULL         15
Lenovo Laptops  5            1            4
Wrist Watches   9            3            6
```

Comment: `(sum(i.Quantity - r.Quantity)) = (sum(i.Quantity) - sum(r.Quantity))` isn't it ?

Comment: i tried it out but am still getting the wrong answers

Comment: @LBjoshua - As I have asked earlier post your expected result in question

Comment: See updated version. Correctly handling duplicate entries.

Comment: @LBjoshua And one last update fixing problem with no sales for product.

Comment: thanks merek viteck, worked perfectly, the way i wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH stock AS (
SELECT productname, sum(quantity) AS stock
FROM inventory 
GROUP BY productname
)
SELECT productname, stock - sum(r.quantity) AS number_items_left
FROM report_details r
JOIN stock USING (productname)
GROUP BY productname, stock
```

EDIT: You should do a RIGHT JOIN on stock if there are cases when some products aren't sold.